# Grails environments

Tags: grails

I couldn't find an answer in the documentation so I'm asking here.

In Grails when you create an app you get the Production, Development etc environments by default.

If you want to build a WAR for Production you can run either of these commands:

```
grails war
```

OR

```
grails -Dgrails.env=prod war
```

If you want to create a WAR for the development environment you use the command:

```
grails -Dgrails.env=dev war
```

My questions;

1) Can I use the word 'production' instead of 'prod' and use 'development' instead of 'dev'? I assume that 'prod' and 'dev' are just shorthand for 'production' and 'development', so I should be able to use either?

2) If so, if I introduce my own environment called 'Stage' can I create a shorthand for use in setting -Dgrails.env? Something like 'stg' for example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> 1) Can I use the word 'production' instead of 'prod' and use 'development' instead of 'dev'? I assume that 'prod' and 'dev' are just shorthand for 'production' and 'development', so I should be able to use either?

The short answer is yes. You can use either the short name or full name of an environment to the `grails.env` parameter. The short and full names of the environments defined by Grails are shown below

```
short name|full name
prod      |PRODUCTION
dev       |DEVELOPMENT
test      |TEST
```

The value provided for `grails.env` is matched case-insensitively against the short and full name of all environments.

> 2) If so, if I introduce my own
>   environment called 'Stage' can I
>   create a shorthand for use in setting
>   -Dgrails.env? Something like 'stg' for example.

No, the short names are stored within a private static field of `grails.util.Environment`, which you should not access

Comment: Seems so unlike Grails to tie our hands and not let us configure other named environments like Stage/stg as @C0deAttack suggested.